# Qt: Saving an image in intended compression format

Tags: qt, qml, png, jpeg, image-compression

I am using `Qt` and saving a image file out of a `QML` UI item. Following is what I do

```
auto screenshot = quick_item->grabToImage();
screenshot->saveToFile("/somepath/filename.jpeg");
// OR sometimes use like png like
screenshot->saveToFile("/somepath/filename.png");
```

This is works fantastically well on all platforms. I open the file the image is saved as intended.

**Now my question is:**
I just mentioned `.jpeg` as file extension while providing the filename as param into `saveToFile`. This works but, should I need to use `QImageWriter` to ensure that the image is actually compressed in `jpeg`/`png` format ?

What happens when it is a lossy compression like `jpeg`?
How to control a lossy compression if I want to like in android I can do a `image.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, stream)` where 80 is the [percentage of quality for Compress](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that directly from `QQuickItemGrabResult`, you have to use [`QImage::save()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#save) for that :

```
auto screenshot = quick_item->grabToImage();
auto image = screenshot->image();
image.save("/somepath/filename.jpeg", nullptr, 80);
```

The second parameter of save is the format, but it can be left null and then be guessed based on the filename extension, the third one is the compression quality.

<s>The quality factor has no effect if you use a lossless format like png. You can set it at `-1` (the default value), omit the parameter or use a factor that you would use for lossy format.</s>

EDIT: as pointed by @Arsenal, the quality factor maps to compression levels for lossless formats (those that support it). For example in PNG, quality 0 maps to PNG compression level 9 (smallest file size) and 100 to PNG compression level 0 (biggest file size). The default quality for PNG in Qt is 50, mapping to a PNG compression level of 4.

Comment: ah nice. do I need to do this if I am saving a lossless format like `png` as well ? this was a part of my question as well

Comment: Looks like `QImage::Format::` that I can input instead of the `nullptr` has a ton of format selection? What should I choose? I am saving an image which is a color image with many colors & I want all the colors to be displayed as it is

Comment: @HAL9000-Kernel I edited my answer. Also `QImage::Format` is about image formats, not file formats like jpeg or png. The image has an image format that you don't need to change. The file format you could put instead of `nullptr` are the name of the formats, like `"PNG"` or `"JPEG"` as explained here : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#reading-and-writing-image-files

Comment: `screenshot->saveToFile("/somepath/filename.png")` also is working as I said in my question. I open the file saved & it contains the data fine, **What do I loose if I don't follow your way of taking the image & calling save on it when using a .png as file extension ?**

Comment: Nothing. `screenshot->saveToFile("/somepath/filename.png")` does the same thing as `screenshot->image().save("/somepath/filename.png")`. The file format is not needed since it can be guessed by the png extension and the quality factor is of no use since it's lossless.

Comment: In case of PNG the quality is used to define the compression of the PNG, eg 100 will lead to no compression and huge files, 0 will lead to best compression and smallest files.